# Typescript- How do I use dynamic key in Object property

Tags: typescript

Is there something like this possible?

assuming we have type `DynamicObj`:

```
type DynamicObj = {
  [`some/[number]`]: number;
  [`some/[string]`]: string;
}
```

the `[number]` or `[string]` means dynamic content, which should be restricted as number/string.

```
type a = DynamicObj['some/1']; // should be "number"
type b = DynamicObj['some/sdfs'] // should be "string"
```

Anybody have some idea about this?

**EDIT:**

thanks to @jcalz, I tried to change `DynamicObj` into generic type so that I can infer type according to the generic T：

```
type DynamicObj<T> = T extends `num/${number}` ? number : T extends `str/${string}` ? string : never;

type a = DynamicObj<`num/1`>; // we got "number" here

type b = DynamicObj<`str/sdf`>; // we got "string" here
```

but this solution is not quite "elegant". If we want to add more property to DynamicObj, we will end up to "Conditional operator hell" :(

Comment: You can write `\`some/${number}\`` and `\`some/${string}\``, but the latter is a supertype of the former... the string `"some/1"` matches both of those, so the type would have to be both `number` *and* `string`.  And no, there's no type in TypeScript corresponding to "strings that cannot be interpreted as numbers", so you cannot represent `DynamicObj` as a specific type.  What would you like to do instead?  You can change it to `\`num/${number}\`` and `\`str/${string}\`` so there's no namespace collision; you can change it so that `\`some/${string}\`` yields `string | number`; you can...

Comment: ...change it so that `DynamicObj` is a generic type function and `DynamicObj<"some/1">` is `number` while `DynamicObj<"some/sdfs">` is `string`, etc.  Depending on your reply (and an appropriate [edit] to the question) we can proceed.